# Find a basis for the submodule $\mathbb Z^3$ consisting of all integer solutions of the system of equations $x+2y+3z=0, x+4y+9z=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, modules

> Find a basis for the submodule $\mathbb Z^3$ consisting of all integer solutions of the system of equations $x+2y+3z=0, x+4y+9z=0$.

$$\begin{align*}
x +2y +3z &=0\\
x+4y+9z &=0\\
\end{align*}$$

Then the augmented matrix is:

$$
        \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 2 & 3 &0\\
        1 & 4 & 9 &0\\
        \end{array}\right]
$$

Reduced Row Echelon Form $\to$

$$
        \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
        1 & 0 & -3 &0\\
        0 & 1 & 3 &0\\
                \end{array}\right]
$$

So a basis for the solution set is $$\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}\}$$

I don't think this is the answer they want though because they talk about integer solutions.

I would appreciate some help/guidance pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: You computed it well, but the conclusion is not correct. Solution set it generated by $[3,-3,1]$, not by $[1,2,3]$.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your solution in equations. You have obtained 
$$
x=3z,\quad y=-3z.
$$
So you can choose any integer $z$. It determines $(x,y,z)=(3z,-3z,z)$.
So the basis is $(3,-3,1)$.